# How to select from dropdown menu

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

This image shows what Inspect Element brings up when I Inspect the Dropdown menu

[image: This image shows what Inspect Element brings up when I Inspect the Dropdown menu]

When I change the size on the website dropbox it just changes the Span value?

I tried too select the value from here but that didnt work either..

[image: I tried too select the value from here but that didnt work either..]

So I'm just messing about trying to fill some forms in online, I've used Select to select from dropdown, but I've came across a site where I can't use Select.. I'm not too sure of the reason. I can fill in the info and manage to click on the dropdown menu, but can't select a value. Please help, I've been trying too figure this out for hours now :(

I've tried using Select didn't work, I tried using Xpath but Im not very familiar with it so that didnt work either.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

browser = webdriver.Chrome ('C:\\Users\\Billy\\driver\\chromedriver.exe')
browser.get('https://www.random.com/launches')

browser.find_element_by_id('mce-EMAIL').send_keys('random@hotmail.com')
browser.find_element_by_id('mce-FNAME').send_keys('firstname')
browser.find_element_by_id('mce-LNAME').send_keys('lastname')
browser.find_element_by_id('mce_SIZE_chosen').click()
```

How can I select from the dropdown menu? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Post the html for the drop down. Most likely you need to click the drop down first to expand the selection. Then select the value by name.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the HTML code you've posted there is a [HTML `<select>` element](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) in the page so you can use [Select](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.select) class for easy interaction with the dropdown.

Example code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("mce-SIZE"))
select.select_by_visible_text("11")
```

If you're having problems with the defining the relevant XPath locator for the element you can consider using [Appium Studio](https://experitest.com/mobile-test-automation/appium-studio/) which provides [`Copy Unique XPath`](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TC/AS+-+Copy+Unique+XPath) feature, however if the element has [`id` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp) it's better to stick to the [ID location strategy](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-id) as it is the fastest way of finding the elements, moreover it has less footprint in terms of CPU/RAM.

More information: [Filling in forms](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#filling-in-forms)